# Problem in computing complex integrals for fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, complex-integration, dirac-delta

This is from a problem set of open course 8.02 by MIT OCW. I am not able to understand how the integral was solved. I have basic knowledge of Fourier transformation, and the Dirac delta function (somehow, I have a feeling that it may be in play here).

PS: I have just completed high school, so please try to explain it as per that knowledge level. 
Furthermore, as mentioned above, I am taking this course voluntarily without credits, certification, so I guess its not violating any honour code.
[image: expression]

Comment: Do you understand substitution of variables for integration?

Comment: @Dr.MV yes, I have used that before.

Comment: You also need to collect together all the powers to get $e^\text{stuff}$, and then complete the square with the stuff.

Comment: Then you do the substitution.  But its a bit tricky because you have to do a substitution of the form $x \mapsto x+b$, where $b$ is a complex number.  So you have to trust that you can do the substitution, and push the limits of $\pm \infty$ off a little bit in an imaginary direction.  To justify this step, you need to know some complex variable theory.

Comment: @StephenMontgomery-Smith, I was thinking of using the delta function for $e^{i(k_0 -  k)x} = \delta (k_0 - k)$, but that doesn't work out because  the delta function and the integral are in different variables.

Comment: Yes, I don't know how that could be made to work.  I will tell you this - it's a fairly standard integral, but I suspect most people saw someone else do it first.  So there really isn't any shame in not figuring it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, let $y=\frac{x-x_0}{a}$.  Then,

$$\begin{align}
\frac{N}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x-x_0)^2/a}e^{ik_0x}e^{-ikx}dx&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}e^{-i(k-k_0)(ay+x_0))}dy\\\\
&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}e^{-i(k-k_0)ay}dy\tag 1
\end{align}$$

Now, let's complete the square on the exponent by writing

$$y^2+i(k-k_0)ay=(y-\frac12i(k-k_0)a)^2+\frac{(k-k_0)a^2}{4}\tag 2$$

Substituting $(2)$ into $(1)$ reveals

$$\begin{align}
\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}e^{-i(k-k_0)ay}dy&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(y-\frac12i(k-k_0)a)^2}e^{-\frac{(k-k_0)a^2}{4}}dy\\\\
&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-\frac{(k-k_0)a^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(y-\frac12i(k-k_0)a)^2}dy\\\\
&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-\frac{(k-k_0)a^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-y^2}dy\\\\
&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-\frac{(k-k_0)a^2}{4}}\sqrt{\pi}\\\\
&=\frac{Na}{\sqrt{2}}e^{-i(k-k_0)x_0}e^{-\frac{(k-k_0)a^2}{4}}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Great! I understood it completely. Thanks! But I doubt I would have been able to figure it out myself...

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.  Don't worry. It takes time to gain the requisite experience.  You can do it!